# How to set up onion service?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, tor

I want to serve [a website](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-run-stash-box-bare-metal/124582) through tor, so that I don't have to pay a hosting service or provide my ip to the users.

I've followed the steps on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tor) and [torproject.org](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/):

### Step 0: Get a working Tor

```
$ yay -S tor
$ sudo systemctl enable --now tor.service
```

### Step 1: Get a web server working

[Previous steps](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-run-stash-box-bare-metal/124582).

```
$ cd ~/code/go/stash-box
$ ./stash-box --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9998 &
```

### Step 2: Configure your Tor Onion Service

Added this lines to `/etc/tor/torrc`

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/media_wiki/
HiddenServicePort 9998 127.0.0.1:9998
```

### Step 3: Restart Tor and check that it worked

```
$ sudo systemctl restart tor
```

### Step 4: Test that your Onion Service works

When I visit the address in `/var/lib/tor/media_wiki/hostname` with the Tor Browser I see an `Unable to connect` message.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HiddenServicePort 9998 127.0.0.1:9998` means that, in order to access it, you will need to browse to `<hostname>:9998` in the Tor Browser.

If you just want the default HTTP port, you can use `HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:9998` and you could add HTTPS with `HiddenServicePort 443 127.0.0.1:9998`.